# Condition for hypersurfaces in $\mathbb{R}^n$ to be diffeomorphic?

Tags: geometry, analysis, derivatives, differential-geometry

Let $n \geq 2$ and consider two hypersurfaces $H_1$ and $H_2$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$, as well as an application $\phi: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$,such that the restriction of $\phi$ from $H_1$ is bijective with values in $H_2$. What are in general the conditions required for the application $\phi$ viewed as an application from $H_1$ to $H_2$ to be diffeomorphic? Do I need to check that the derivative of $\phi$ does not cancel on the tangent space of any point of $H_1$?

Any reference on this kind of problem would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you asking what are the conditions such that the restricted map $\phi : H_1 \to H_2$ is a diffeomorphism? Or are you allowing that restriction to fail to be a diffeomorphisms, and *still* wanting to know whether $H_1$ and $H_2$ are diffeomorphic?

Comment: The first one I believe.

Comment: Here is a sufficient condition for the restricted map $\phi : H_1 \to H_2$ to be a diffeomorphism: $\phi$ itself is a diffeomorphism, and $H_1$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb R^n$. Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Not really, I think this condition is not restrictive enough for what I want to do. For instance if I want to show that the surface of a convex set is diffeomorphic to the unit sphere, finding a map that is diffeomorphic from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to itself would be quite hard I think.

Comment: But the surface of a convex set is *not* diffeomorphic to the unit sphere. Take the unit cube $[0,1]^n$, for example.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I meant strictly convex.

Comment: Even strictly convex is not enough. Fatten up the unit cube a little: for each of its four sides, connect the endpoints of that side by the arc of a circle centered on the midpoint of the opposite side. This is strictly convex, but the four corners of the square continue to be nonsmooth points. And there are worse examples, where the subset of nonsmooth points is dense in the boundary.

Comment: Thus if 0 belongs to the interior of the set, $x \to \frac{x}{\|x\|}$ is not diffeomorphic in the sense I am looking for? What about if I also assume the boundary to be regular, for instance $C^1$?

Comment: But at that point, your question has answered itself: if the boundary is $C^1$ then it is $C^1$-diffeomorphic to the circle; if the boundary is $C^2$ then it is $C^2$ diffeomorphic to the circle; and so on.

Comment: And can the application $x \to \frac{x}{\|x\|}$ be such diffeomorphism? My problem is that at first glance this application is from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$. Is there a chance to explicitely compute its jacobian matrix ?

Comment: At this point, I'm not sure any more what remnant there is of your original question. I suggest you figure out what your question should currently be, and re-ask it in a new question.

Comment: I rephrased my question to reflect what I am looking for.